# Redirect an specific folder to a subdomain but without the folder name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to do a rewrite for only the subfolder example.com/b to another domain.

example:

`www.example.com/a/name` --> doesn't redirect

`www.example.com/b/name` --> `console.example.com/name` '**note that the `b` is not present on the subdomain**

How would it be the `RewriteCond + RewriteRule / RewriteMatch` command?

this what i have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/b/?$


RewriteRule ([a-z0-9_-]*[\/]?)$ https://console.example.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Here is a copy of the current htaccess.conf file:

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(tucita247\.com)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^b/(.*)$ https://console.%1/$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
</Directory>
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/akismet">
# Only allow direct access to specific Web-available files.
# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
# Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
# Akismet CSS and JS
<FilesMatch "^(form\.js|akismet\.js|akismet\.css)$">
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# Akismet images
<FilesMatch "^logo-full-2x\.png$">
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[4.0.6]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
```

WORDPRESS htaccess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks!

Comment: please show your attempted rule

Comment: hi, i just added to the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect as your topmost rule in site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^b/(.*)$ https://console.tucita247.com/$1 [R=302,NC,NE,L]
```

- Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.
- Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: Thanks. It is redirecting other request than /b/. For example example.com/terms-conditions/ is being redirected

Comment: Hi, just add the current full file above, thanks!

Comment: I am using a bitnami wordpress isntance, this is the htaccess.conf from the apache. point to the htaccess of the wordpress wich have the content i put above

Comment: ok try adding my suggested rule in Wordpress .htaccess below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: seems to be working but only if i type www.domain.com/b/ it is not in the case of domain.com/b/

Comment: ok try updated rule. I have made `www.` part optional

Comment: ok, now if i type domain.com/b/content it redirects to console./content giving a 404

Comment: yes it is there. I did change console.%1 to console.tucita247.com/$1 and it worked! thanks!